# Hammerjs tap and swipedown

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, hammer.js

How to implement drag-down to trigger an event in angular material using hammerjs?

Like below image on gray bar just above facebook button the dragdown event needs to be done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to add Hammer is't only add in the main.module

```
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';
```

If you want to change the config add too

```
import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Add a class

```
export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = <any> {
    swipe: { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL },
  };
}
```

And use as provider

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
      useClass: MyHammerConfig,
    },
  ],
```

See an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujasue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

NOTE: is (swipeDown) waht are you looking for?

Comment: Not like to swipeDown. It must be like hold and dragDown to dismiss.